# How to compare user input with string?

Tags: c++, linux, string, compare

I want to compare user input (text) with already declared string in c++ under linux (code::blocks)
i made something like this, but it doesn't work

```
int LoadModule()
{
    string test1 = "LOAD DEFAULT DATABASE";
    string test2;
    cout << "select cmd: " << endl;
    cin >> test2;
    //todo: compare thoose 2 strings. And if they are equal, print "done"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `std::getline()` to input a `std::string` containing white space characters:

```
std::getline(std::cin, test2);
```

doing so a simple comparison

```
if(test1 == test2) {
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
```

should work.

---

You should note that `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)` will just copy from input up to the first whitespace character (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`) is met.